# Difference between HttpContext GetLocalResourceObject and GetGlobalResourceObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

Is there a difference between these two methods?

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("test.aspx", "Button1.Text").ToString();
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("test.aspx", "Button1.Text").ToString();
```

My assumption was that `GetLocalResourceObject()` would take a single parameter of `resourceKey` and implicitly pick up the virtual path.

I'll just use the TemplateControl methods for which `GetLocalResourceObject()` only takes 1 argument but the question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post: 
http://juristr.com/blog/2011/01/aspnet-organize-your-resources-correct/

You should organize your resources...

Comment: please, add come comment to your answer, as the link may get broken.

Comment: As @GoogleHireMe pointed out, if the link goes dead or is blocked by firewall, etc., your answer has no information other than to say that there was once an article which was useful. Please edit your answer to include the relevant parts of your link - leave the link as reference if you wish. Thank you.

Comment: The question isn't "what is the difference between local and global resources"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, the real answer was buried in there...

Local resources are for a particular page - and are usually named to match the page - and generally stored in the folder with the page that it is for.

Global resources are for your whole project - and live in a folder called App_GlobalResources.